# detecting white space characters, \t, \n, etc

Tags: c++

I am working through c++ primer 5th edition. the exercise in chapter 5 states the follow:

> Exercise 5.11: Write a program that counts the number of blank spaces, tabs, and newlines read.

I attempted to do as exercise 5.11 did with the below code. However the code fails. Can anyone provide some examples of how i would correct the code so that when the input is read that the counter `unsigned int cnt = 0;` will be iterated correctly?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    unsigned int cnt = 0;
    char c1;
    while (std::cin >> c1)
        if (c1 == '\t' || c1 == '\n' || c1 == ' ')
            ++cnt;
    std::cout << "The number of spaces,tabs, newlines are: " << cnt << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'/n'` such thing doesn't exist. I believe you meant `'\n'`.

Comment: Is this a typo? `c1 == '/n'`. It should be `c1 == '\n'`.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the code fails?"  What output do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: I suggest you always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, and eliminate all warnings. It should have warned you about using a multi-character-constant.

Comment: Don't do a `system("pause")`, read a line from `std::cin` instead.

Comment: @zmbq: surely you mean `ignore()` something as in `std::cin.ignore();`? Note, that both reading a line and ignoring anything has the somewhat unfortunate problem that it will be instantanously successful if the last operation on `std::cin` was a formatted read: if so, you'd first want to ignore the trailing characters on the line using `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. I certainly don't think `system("pause");` should be used but we really need a good alternative. Even `std:cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail())` isn't substantially better...

Comment: maybe you should take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ on section "cin and strings"

Comment: @ Dan Korn: what i mean by fail is, the code does not count(cnt) the tab, space, or new line as i an trying to get the code to do. What i expect as an output for example: Input = "This is a test". the output should be ""The number of spaces,tabs, newlines are: 3" as there was 3 spaces in the input.

@Havenard: yes it is a typo. i will fix it in the post.

@ ZMBQ: i am using microsoft VB 2013 express. i used `system("pause");` to pause the terminal screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to classify characters in C++ are the functions from `<cctype>` or the functions from `<locale>`: there are `std::isspace()` functions in both of these. Note, that you can only pass positive `int` values to the functions from `<cctype>`, i.e., to determine if a `char c` is a space you'd use:

```
if (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))) {
    // c is a space
}
```

Just using `std::isspace(c)` result in undefined behavior if `char` is signed and `c` is a negative value. On typical systems non-ASCII characters (or multiple bytes of a UTF-8 encoding) use negative values.

The problems in your original code are:

- `'/n'` is not a valid character literal; you probably meant to use `'\n'`.
- You omitted a number of space characters, e.g., `'\r'` (carriage return) and `'\v'` (vertical space)
- By default the formatted input operators skip all leading whitespace. To avoid this you can use `std::cin >> std::noskipws;`. Personally, I would use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` to get the characters. I guess, this is your primary problem.

The pragmatic approach to count spaces is probably something like this:

```
unsigned long spaces = std::count_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std:cin),
                                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                                     [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
```

Comment: @ Dietmar Kuhl: I used the `STD::noskipws` to make the code work. thank you. the rest of your suggested code is a bit further than i have made it in C++ thus far. so i kept it simple until the book teaches me more. However! thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user3089453 another alternative to `noskipws` is to do `cin.get(c1)` .

Comment: @Dietmar the question specified "blank spaces, tabs, and newlines" so arguably OP should be testing individual characters rather than `isspace` . Still useful info of course